# How to combine multiple rows of employee into single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm having following table and below is expected results. Please let me known if there is a easy to way to get the expected results in SQL server.

```
EmpNo Name   Benefit   StartDate     Status
--------------------------------------------
0001  ABC    Medical   01/01/2014    Active
0001  ABC    Dental    02/02/2013    Inactive
0001  ABC    Vision    03/03/2012    Active
0002  XYZ    Medical   01/01/2014    Active
0002  XYZ    Dental    02/02/2008    Inactive
```

The results should be like below

```
EmpNo   Name  MedicalStart MedStatus  DenStart  DenStatus VisionStart     VisStatus
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0001    ABC   01/01/2014    Active    02/02/2013    Inactive   03/03/2012    Active
0002    XYZ   01/01/2014    Active    02/02/2008    Inactive                       .
```

**I forgot put a few notes in my initial post.**

1) There are 10 benefit plans available, so an employee may enroll for any number of plans up to ten (all plan or few plan or no plans at all).

2) There will be only one row with same benefit plan per EmpNo/Name.

3) Also, there are several fields associated with each row, for example, election option (Self, Family, etc) and many more. To make it simple, I have not included in the question.

Comment: What is the source of data in `DenStart`, `DenStatus`, `VisionStart`, `VisStatus` columns? I looks like data structure you've provided is incomplete...

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I think they are depending on the `Benifit` col value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your responses. I forgot put a note in my initial post. There are 10 benefit plans available, so an employee may enroll for any number of plans up to 10. Also, there are several fields associated with each row, for example, election option (Self, Family, etc) and many more.

Comment: There may still be time to update your question. Also, please clarify whether there can be multiple rows with the same `Benefit` per `EmpNo, Name`.

Comment: Is the number benefit plans dynamic? In the OP, there are 3. If this is a fixed number then query can be made. But for dynamic benefits, a totally different approach is required.

Comment: There will be only one row with same benefit plan per EmpNo/Name.

Comment: The number of benefit plans will be fixed, that is 10 benefit plans. But, employee may elect all plan or few plan or no plans at all.

Comment: My query can be expanded to 10 benefits but may not be very efficient. For employees who have not elected some plans, the corresponding columns will show null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    EmpNo INT
    , Name VARCHAR(255)
    , Benefit VARCHAR(255)
    , StartDate DATETIME2
    , Status VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO #Test
    (EmpNo, Name, Benefit, StartDate, Status)
VALUES
    (0001, 'ABC', 'Medical', '01/01/2014', 'Active')
    , (0001, 'ABC', 'Dental', '02/02/2013', 'Inactive')
    , (0001, 'ABC', 'Vision', '03/03/2012', 'Active')
    , (0002, 'XYZ', 'Medical', '01/01/2014', 'Active')
    , (0002, 'XYZ', 'Dental', '02/02/2008', 'Inactive')
```

And a simple group clause:

**Actual query (if there are historical records), using ROW_NUMBER will let you find latest record for each User and its Benefit:**

```
SELECT T.EmpNo
    , T.Name
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Medical ' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDate, 106), 103) END) AS MedStart
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Medical' THEN T.Status END) AS MedStatus
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Dental ' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDate, 106), 103) END) AS DenStart
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Dental' THEN T.Status END) AS DenStatus
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Vision ' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDate, 106), 103) END) AS VisStart
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Vision' THEN T.Status END) AS VisStatus
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpNo, Name, Benefit ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS RowNo
        , EmpNo
        , Benefit
        , Name
        , StartDate
        , Status
    FROM #Test
) AS T
WHERE T.RowNo = 1
GROUP BY T.EmpNo
    , T.Name
```

**Query using dynamic SQL if there is unknown amount of Benefits. Might not be very efficient:**

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT T.EmpNo, T.Name'
    , @Benefit VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL += ', MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = ''' + Benefit + ''' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDate, 106), 103) END) AS ' + LEFT(Benefit, 3) + 'Star
                , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = ''' + Benefit + ''' THEN T.Status END) AS ' + LEFT(Benefit, 3) + 'Status'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Benefit FROM #Test) AS T

SET @SQL += '
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpNo, Name, Benefit ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS RowNo, EmpNo, Benefit, NAME, StartDate, STATUS
    FROM #Test
    ) AS T
WHERE T.RowNo = 1
GROUP BY T.EmpNo, T.Name'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Query (if there are no historical records):**

```
SELECT T.EmpNo
    , T.Name
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Medical ' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDate, 106), 103) END) AS MedStart
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Medical' THEN T.Status END) AS MedStatus
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Dental ' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDate, 106), 103) END) AS DenStart
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Dental' THEN T.Status END) AS DenStatus
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Vision ' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDate, 106), 103) END) AS VisStart
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.Benefit = 'Vision' THEN T.Status END) AS VisStatus
FROM #Test AS T
GROUP BY T.EmpNo
    , T.Name
```

**Output:**

```
EmpNo   Name    MedStart    MedStatus   DenStart    DenStatus   VisStart    VisStatus
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       ABC     01/01/2014  Active      02/02/2013  Inactive    03/03/2012  Active
2       XYZ     01/01/2014  Active      02/02/2008  Inactive    NULL        NULL
```

Comment: The `MedStatus` column will always return "InActive" if there is even record inactive as it gets the alphabetical max from all records and not just the latest record. Same goes for `DenStatus` and `VisStatus`.

Comment: I've made some corrections. Coul you, perhaps, review it?

Comment: I'm using it to get latest Activity/InActivity status together with date for each User and its Benefit.

Comment: @navigator: Why should you think there would be multiple rows with identical Benefit per employee?

Comment: Why not? Table might contain historical data with status changes for each user and its benefit. For example: http://prntscr.com/69zkp8

Comment: Yes I understand that may be the case *in some situations*. But what makes @navigator or you think it is the case here? At least you should have explained the purpose of ROW_NUMBER. And maybe you should have kept your original version too, in case the OP doesn't actually keep historical records (and so doesn't need ROW_NUMBER at all).

Comment: I assumed that, as with any medical record system, it would maintain a history of records as well and not just the latest record. I could be wrong, but my solution will work either way.

Comment: I've added both queries to my answer, User can pick whatever he wants.

Comment: @navigator: It likely will. It might just not be equally efficient in the two scenarios (with/without history records).

Answer (score 1):

`PIVOT` solution on `StartDate` field:

```
DECLARE @tb AS TABLE
(
    EmpNo INT
    ,Name NVARCHAR(25)
    ,Benefit NVARCHAR(25)
    ,StartDate DATE
    ,[Status] NVARCHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (1, 'ABC', 'Medical', '01/01/2014', 'Active');
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (1, 'ABC', 'Dental', '02/02/2013', 'Inactive');
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (1, 'ABC', 'Vision', '03/03/2012', 'Active');
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (2, 'XYZ', 'Medical', '01/01/2014', 'Active');
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (2, 'XYZ', 'Dental', '02/02/2012', 'Inactive');

SELECT EmpNo
    ,Name
    ,MAX(MedicalStart) AS MedicalStart
    ,MAX(MedStatus) AS MedStatus
    ,MAX(DenStart) AS DenStart
    ,MAX(DenStatus) AS DenStatus
    ,MAX(VisionStart) AS VisionStart
    ,MAX(VisStatus) AS VisStatus
FROM
(
    SELECT EmpNo
        ,Name
        ,[Medical] AS MedicalStart
        ,CASE 
            WHEN [Medical] IS NOT NULL AND [Status] = 'Active' THEN 'Active' 
            WHEN [Medical] IS NOT NULL AND [Status] = 'Inactive' THEN 'Inactive' 
            ELSE NULL END AS MedStatus
        ,[Dental] AS DenStart
        ,CASE 
            WHEN [Dental] IS NOT NULL AND [Status] = 'Active' THEN 'Active' 
            WHEN [Dental] IS NOT NULL AND [Status] = 'Inactive' THEN 'Inactive' 
            ELSE NULL END AS DenStatus
        ,[Vision] AS VisionStart
        ,CASE 
            WHEN [Vision] IS NOT NULL AND [Status] = 'Active' THEN 'Active' 
            WHEN [Vision] IS NOT NULL AND [Status] = 'Inactive' THEN 'Inactive' 
            ELSE NULL END AS VisStatus
        ,[Status]
    FROM @tb
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(StartDate)
        FOR Benefit IN ([Medical], [Dental], [Vision])
    ) AS pivotTableDate
) AS tb
GROUP BY EmpNo, Name;
```

You can check [this link 'PIVOT on two or more fields in SQL Server'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kenobonn/archive/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server.aspx) for information about full PIVOT solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for each employee you have at most 1 row for Medical, at most 1 row for Dental, and at most 1 row for Vision. If so, you can do it like this:

```
select 

    t.EmpNo, t.Name, 
    tMedical.MedicalStart, tMedical.MedicalStatus

from 
(
    select
        EmpNo, Name
    from 
        TableName
    group by EmpNo, Name
) t

left outer join

(

    select 
        EmpNo, Name, Benefit, 
        min(StartDate) as MedicalStart, 
        min(Status) as MedicalStatus
    from 
        TableName
    where
        Benefit = 'Medical'
    group by EmpNo, Name, Benefit

) tMedical on t.EmpNo = tMedical.EmpNo and t.Name = tMedical.Name

left outer join ...
```

Analogically to `tMedical`, you can add here left joins to `tDental` and `tVision`. And that should be it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Outer Apply` to do this. I am assuming that one employee can have any number of medical, dental and vision rows. This query will take the latest `StartDate` for each type.

```
Select EmpNo, Name, Medical.StartDate MedicalStart, Medical.Status MedStatus, Dental.StartDate DenStart, Dental.Status DenStatus, Vision.StartDate VisionStart, Vision.Status VisStatus
From (Select Distinct EmpNo, Name From TableName) Emp
Outer Apply (Select Top 1 StartDate, Status From TableName Med Where Benefit='Medical' and Med.EmpNo=Emp.EmpNo Order By StartDate Desc) Medical
Outer Apply (Select Top 1 StartDate, Status From TableName Den Where Benefit='Dental' and Den.EmpNo=Emp.EmpNo Order By StartDate Desc) Dental
Outer Apply (Select Top 1 StartDate, Status From TableName Vis Where Benefit='Vision' and Vis.EmpNo=Emp.EmpNo Order By StartDate Desc) Vision
```

Let me know if this works for you...